# Alert message when input is greater or lower than 16 digits

Tags: jquery, sweetalert, variable-length

I have created this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="profile.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Card Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7"> 
            <input type="text" id="card_no" class="form-control" name="card_number" maxlength="16" autofocus="autofocus">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary demo1" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="check()">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

When the card's length is greater or lower than 16 an alert message must be displayed. So I tried this:

```
$('#submit').onclick(function() {
    var inputlength = $('#card_no').val().length;
    if (inputlength<>16) {
        sweetAlert("ERROR", "Card must have 16 digits", "warning");
        return false;
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. I also have an alert when there is NO input and works fine! Any ideas?

Comment: In Javascript the 'not equal to' operator is `!=`, not `<>`: `if (inputlength != 16)...`

Comment: I have tried it but still no message alert!

Comment: There may be other errors in your code, try checking the console. You can remove the `onclick="check()"` attribute on your submit button too

Comment: So what errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: yes remove ``onclick="check()"`` and it will work.

Comment: ``var inputlength = $('#card_no').val().length;`` why you are check the length ?

Comment: @Neelesh because it's the requirement of the input to be 16 characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if(inputlength !== 16)`

```js
$('#submit').on('click',function() {
  var inputlength = $('#card_no').val().length;
  if (inputlength !== 16) {
    sweetAlert("ERROR", "Card must have 16 digits", "warning");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="profile.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Card Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" id="card_no" class="form-control" name="card_number" maxlength="16" autofocus="autofocus">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary demo1" type="submit" id="submit">SEARCH</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just change `alert` with your `sweetAlert`

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var inputlength = $('#card_no').val().length;
    if (inputlength!=16) {
        alert("ERROR", "Card must have 16 digits", "warning");
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="profile.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Card Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7"> 
            <input type="text" id="card_no" class="form-control" name="card_number" maxlength="16" autofocus="autofocus">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary demo1" type="submit" id="submit">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sweetAlert is a plugin

Comment: yeah i know. i used ``alert`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

See the example below and make adjustments if necessary. Using `!=` sets it so that when entered value is lesser-than or greater-than the defined value, the alert will be triggered.

```js
$('#submit').on("click", function() {
  
  var $inputlength = $('#card_no').val();
  
  if ($inputlength != 16) {
    
    alert('ERROR, Card must have 16 digits. "warning!"'); 
    
    /* Change "alert" to sweetAlert */
    
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="profile.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Card Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" id="card_no" class="form-control" name="card_number" maxlength="16" autofocus="autofocus">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="submit" ">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to name your function `check()` if you want to call the function. Also, the logic operator is not correct, there is a <>, and a < is needed to test the input.

```
$('#submit').onclick(function check() {

          var inputlength = $('#card_no').val().length;

         if (inputlength<16) {
        alert("ERROR", "Card must have 16 digits", "warning");
                return false;
       }
     });
```

Comment: edited my answer, just notice the logic operator was incorrect.

Comment: Maybe try using onclick="submit", instead of check(), If  your just using `function () {}`

Comment: `just notice the logic operator was incorrect` And it still is

Comment: Given that the OP has set `maxlength` on the element `> 16` will never be true. You should use either `< 16` or `!= 16`

Comment: ah, did not account for the max length, !=, would be the most accurate, though not all card numbers are 16 digits...

Comment: I changed the answer to <, if the card number really is 16 digits, then != could be used.